# Highcharts organization charts - nodes displayed incorrectly

Tags: highcharts

we have been trying to implement Highcharts organization charts into our system. However, we encountered some problems while testing with our data:

•   Some nodes are displayed incorrectly. The data is shown in the tooltip while hovering over the node, but the node itself is blank.
•   The connecting lines between the nodes are displayed incorrectly. This seems to be a problem with highcharts.css, as removing it fixes the display issue.

Here you can find an example of our build:

```
Code: https://jsfiddle.net/more_paeg/0b52hajt/28/
```

Please let us know what we can do to resolve these issues.

regards, Bianca Medek

Comment: Here is a simplified version of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r4o7Lqu5/. Could you explain more precisely and steps to reproduce the issue to get understand what is wrong with it?

Comment: In my example in node "User 2" the Task 5 is empty. But with mouseover you can see that the task should be shown as "Task 5". The same is in node "User 4" and "Task 2". I don't know why the data are not displayed.

Comment: Seems to displays fine: https://jsfiddle.net/more_paeg/0b52hajt/28/

Comment: This is the output we have been receiving. (https://www.more-software.at/umedia/img/highcharts_error.png) The code has been tested on different browsers on different devices, all of them have produced the same result. The red markers show the missing node texts while the yellow ones show a feint gray triangle coviering the connecting lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the comments - thank you for sharing the picture. That's how you chart looks like on my device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Ua8.jpg

I think that it might be a problem related to this bug (which has been already fixed and will be available in the npm after the next release): https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13100

Try to use suggested workaround - `Setting the series.dataLabels.allowOverlap forces labels to be displayed.`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4dskhf6r/

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: true
      }
    }
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.allowOverlap